# Which js library is to use for making face distortion application using html5?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, distortion

I use iphone face fun and other online face distortion application based on flash. I want to make such app using pure html5. I have looked on pixastic library but it doesn't have any image distortion filters.
Is it possible to twirl, warp or bulge the image using just js library ?
I also have searched on stackoverflow for similar questions, but none have pointed to any specific library.
It would be better provide some html5 face distorting application examples online if any.

Comment: It is, and it doesn't require any library. Just implement the distortion you want yourself.

Comment: ok, I have found the library [jsmanipulate](http://joelb.me/jsmanipulate/) which has more than 40 image filters with twirl, whirl, lens distortion which can be used for distorting face. I came to know about this js library from [ep4f.com](http://ep4f.com) which also implement this library for making "face fun" application.